# How to split the aws:username policy variable to check if permission has granted to write into it?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation

How to split the username, take the 3rd element when splitting on '-' delimiter and matching that element with the folderName inside bucket/?

aws:username is only a placer when writing to a specific bucket. Which means it's not there when creating the policy. Which causes the split to fail.

I tried moving the logic to the condition field but no result yet.

```
  Resources:
    testTagGroupPolicy:
      Type: AWS::IAM::Group
      Properties:
        GroupName: !Sub "test-tag-group-${Environment}"
        Policies:
          - PolicyName: !Sub "test-tag1-group-policy-${Environment}"
            PolicyDocument:
              Version: 2012-10-17
              Statement:
                - Sid: AllowAllActionsInUserFolder
                  Effect: Allow
                  Action:
                    - s3:*
                  Resource: !Sub "arn:aws:s3:::test-tag1-bucket-${Environment}"
                  Condition:
                    StringLikeIfExists:
                      "s3:prefix": !Sub
                        - ${Application}/*"
                        - Application: !Select
                            - 2
                            - !Split ["-", !Sub "${aws:username}"]
```

Let's say we have a bucket called: `test1`

We have a user with name `test-tag1-team1-dev`

Then that user should only be able to write in `test1/team1` folder.
so instead of using the full username, only use the third element.

Comment: Have you considered tagging your IAM principals instead? You can use these tags in policy conditions to control access. https://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/UserGuide/access_iam-tags.html

Answer (score 0):

I ran into the same issue and followed Vikyol suggestion of tagging IAM principals. 
My example is just to allow PutObject request on a specific folder name. Notice how we are assigning Tag while creating a user. We use the tagged Folder name in our policy.

```
Resources:
  testTagGroupPolicy:
    Type: AWS::IAM::Group
    Properties:
      GroupName: !Sub "test-tag-group-${Environment}"
      Policies:
        - PolicyName: !Sub "test-tag1-group-policy-${Environment}"
          PolicyDocument:
            Version: 2012-10-17
            Statement:
              - Sid: AllowUploadInUserFolder
                Effect: Allow
                Action:
                  - s3:PutObject
                Resource:
                  - Fn::Join:
                    - ""
                    -
                      - "arn:aws:s3:::test-tag1-bucket-${Environment}"
                      - "/test1/${aws:PrincipalTag/FolderName}/*"      # This will resolve to /test1/team1 for TestTeam1User

              # For list object the following worked for me
              -  Sid: AllowListObjectInUserFolder
                Effect: Allow
                Action:
                  - s3:ListBucket
                Resource: "arn:aws:s3:::test-tag1-bucket-${Environment}"
                Condition:  
                  StringLike:
                    s3:prefix:
                      - "/test1/${aws:PrincipalTag/FolderName}/*"

  TestTeam1User:
    Type: "AWS::IAM::User"
    Properties: 
      UserName: { "Fn::Join" : ["", ["test-tag1-team1-", { "Ref" : "Environment" } ] ]  }   # Resolves to test-tag1-team1-dev
      Tags: 
        - Key: "FolderName"   # Specify the folder name this user will have access to
          Value: "team1"
```